# Visual Studio 2015 Source control - change project location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, version-control

I am working on a C# console app and I accidentaly saved my solution in a colleague's project. How can I move it under my project folder?

I tried unbinding my solution (File-SourceControl-Advanced) and adding it again  to the version control (File-Add to Source Control). However the version control do not prompt me again for the folder location and automatically adds it to the colleagues folder.

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I am sorry for the lack of clarity. Since I probably messed the terminology, I will try to rephrase my question. Me and a colleague started lately using source control in VS 2015. In source control explorer we have two "parent" folders (for two projects) which contain a number of subfolders (with smaller projects). I created a new project and added it to the source control (File - Add to source control), but accidentally to the wrong "parent" folder. I want to move it under my parent folder.

Comment: Did you try changing the binding?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I stated in my question: "I tried unbinding my solution (File-SourceControl-Advanced)"
Do you mean this or anything else? Please be more specific, I am new to using source control.

Comment: Why not just move (rename) it to the desired folder? You should be clearer about *"solution"* and *"project"* - I suspect you crossed these terms.

Comment: @Filburt You are right probably, I am not well versed in terminology. Edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense now.